# exception in reading data from data grid

Tags: c#, datagridview, nullreferenceexception

I have a weird issue , I have some nested loops, I am reading data from the data grid view.
if i show the same thing in message box,no exception is thrown, when I store the same in string, exception arise . Here is the code ,help

```
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                if (cell.ColumnIndex == 0) //Set your Column Index
                {

                   String auth = cell.Value.ToString();// here nullexception isthrown

                }
```

Comment: show the code when showing in message box

Comment: MessageBox.Show(cell.Value.ToString());

Comment: You are using `String` class, not `string` datatype. I am not sure, but can this be a problem?

Comment: same result with string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid `exception` then you should check for the rows if there are some rows then all the work should be done otherwise it is useless.

```
 if(dataGridView1.Rows.Count>0)
 {
  foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
        foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
        {
            if (cell.ColumnIndex == 0) //Set your Column Index
            {

               string auth = Convert.ToString(cell.Value); 

            }
```

Use `Convert.ToString()` because it also handles `null` values.